# Change of Basis for a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 by $ $$T\left(\left[
\begin{matrix}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
 \end{matrix}\right]\right) = \left[
\begin{matrix}
  x_2 \\
  x_1 \\
 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Let $B$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ where $A$ is the matrix of T. Show that for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$  $$(T(x))_B = Dx_B$$
where D is a diagonal matrix. Interpret this result geometrically.

So I found A to be  $$\left[
\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
 \end{matrix}\right]$$
and the eigenvectors to be $$\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}
  -1 \\
  1 \\
 \end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  1 \\
 \end{matrix}\right]\right\}$$

I understand that $T(x) = A(x)$ so if I take any arbitrary x and multiply with A, I'll get a vector which I need to multiply by the basis. But if I multiply A by and arbitrary x vector and and a Diagonal matrix with the same x vector, I get two different vectors. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is relative to the standard basis and the matrix $D$ is relative to the basis of eigenvectors and $A$ and $D$ are related via the change matrix $P$ by

$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
where $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$ and

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How does that show $(T(x))_B = Dx_B$?

Comment: The subscript in $x_B$ means that we write the vector $x$ relative to the basis $B$ so your equality means that the vector $Tx$ relative to the basis $B$ is equal to $Dx_B$ which is similar to
$$P^{-1}Ax=DP^{-1}x$$
since 
$$x_B=P^{-1}x$$